# How to use new API (JavascriptInterface) when building against an older version of Android (2.2)

Tags: android

I am forking an old project that was meant to run on Froyo.

So I compiled it against 2.2 and everything is OK.

Now I need to use a newer API on that project, namely the `JavascriptInterface`.

Obviously if I compile against 2.2 `JavascriptInterface` is not recognized and gives me an error.

BUT IF I compile against 17, `JavascriptInterface` does not give problems anymore, but I get tons of other errors from APIs that are not supported anymore or that have been updated.

Please how do I behave in such a situation?

---

The errors I get when i compile against 17 are:

- UrlInterceptHandler cannot be resolved to a type
- The method setForeground(boolean) is undefined for the type MailService
- The type Editor must implement the inherited abstract method SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet(String, Set)
- The type Storage must implement the inherited abstract method SharedPreferences.getStringSet(String, Set)

Comment: What are those tons of other errors? You have the choice: either fix the errors and make it compatible with 17 (the latest is 19 btw) or find a way around using `JavascriptInterface`.

Comment: Declare in the manifest minSdkVersion="8", targetSdkVersion="19" and in your code check the the build version for each non-compatible API like this: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) then call your JB compatible api, else call the appropriate api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am forking an old project that was meant to run on Froyo.

No, it was meant to run on Android 1.6 or older. It might have been *capable* of running on Android 2.2. But that code base is ancient, given your errors.

> Now I need to use a newer API on that project, namely the JavascriptInterface.

Only if your `android:targetSdkVersion` is 17 or higher.

> but I get tons of other errors from APIs that are not supported anymore or that have been updated

You will have to fix those.

> UrlInterceptHandler cannot be resolved to a type
>   The method setForeground(boolean) is undefined for the type MailService

Those were deprecated in Android 2.0 and apparently now have been totally removed from the SDK. `setForeground()` was replaced with `startForeground()`; I do not really know what `UrlInterceptHandler` was used for.

> The type Editor must implement the inherited abstract method SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet(String, Set)
>   The type Storage must implement the inherited abstract method SharedPreferences.getStringSet(String, Set)

It is unclear why the code would be trying to *implement* `SharedPreferences` and `SharedPreferences.Editor`. While that is possible -- I did it personally -- it's really unusual. Either reimplement that portion of the app to not create a custom `SharedPreferences` implementation, or extend it to support the required methods.